R ggplot resizes graph plot to less than half the screen size for grouped data
I have an SQL server from where I import data which includes a date column, then convert it to a tibble, summarize, group the data according to a particular variable and plot it with date as x-axis. without grouping the data is plotted on full screen. grouping the data by color correctly assigns individual color to each group but re-sizes the plot to less than half the screen. what am I doing wrong?
The data I import from SQL server is similar to the test data test_Data generated using code below
test_Data <- data.frame(region = sample(c("WER", "EAR", "NOR", "KCR"), 40, replace = TRUE),
                        values = sample(100:200, 40, replace = TRUE),
                        date_time = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2024-04-01"), 
                                             as.Date("2024-05-10"), by = "day"))
#color by region
test_Data %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(date_time, values, colour = region))

So when I run the code, I get a well grouped data but is plotted half the screen. But without grouping by colour, I get a full screen plot but with lines not connecting. See the Image attached Half screen plot
What I expect is a full screen plot as seen in this image.Full screen plot

That looks like potentially some sort of graphic device issue, and I would not expect using different data / grouped data would cause that. Same problem if you restart R?

I could imagine getting something like that from using coord_aspect or from using patchwork or some other plot-compositing functions, but a raw plot like that is unexpected.

If the problem persists, you might also try saving your output directly using ggsave(). If you want to iterate to make sizing adjustments etc., I also recommend the camcorder() package. Those approaches would circumvent whatever weirdness is happening with your Plot Zoom window.

Thanks Jon. on restart I get the same issue. I unfortunately can not use ggsave because the original code is actually for a shiny APP. Interestingly, I only notice issue with data I import from the SQL database even though I convert imported data to a tibble. With excel or any other data source, all is OK. Could it be the format of data from the database

I finally cracked this. Issue was due to excessive white spaces created on string variables for data exported from SQL server. I think this is because each the strings are created in SQL server with a Max char length of 255. I used trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x) to trim the white spaces and all got sorted now.
